# GooglePlayServicesUtil Internal error occurred

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

Trying using Google Drive Android API as [described](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api). But some strange error occurred: `GooglePlayServicesUtil(3662): Internal error occurred. Please see logs for detailed information`.

Previously I had create **Client ID for Android application** in Google Console with SHA1 of my Eclipse (Prefs → Android → Build) and my package name `com.example.googlecloudbuffer`.

May be shoild I use somehow a genereted CLIENT ID or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Google API Console. You must add a Email and Product name as [described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22738951/1621111).