# Open file using Google Drive API's for Android | INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to use the [Google Drive API for Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) to open a file. From the following official [tutorial](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos), I have the following:

GoogleDriveActivity.class

```
public class GoogleDriveActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;
private int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 2;
private ListView filesLv;
private DataBufferAdapter<Metadata> mResultsAdapter;
private String mNextPageToken;
private boolean hasMore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_drive);

    filesLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewResults);
    hasMore = true;
    mResultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this);
    filesLv.setAdapter(mResultsAdapter);
    filesLv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int first, int visible, int total) {
            if (mNextPageToken != null && first + visible + 5 < total) {
                retrieveNextPage();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void retrieveNextPage() {
    // retrieve the results for the next page.
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .setPageToken(mNextPageToken)
            .build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query)
            .setResultCallback(metadataBufferCallback);
}

private final ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> metadataBufferCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    return;
                }
                mResultsAdapter.clear();
                mResultsAdapter.append(result.getMetadataBuffer());
                mNextPageToken = result.getMetadataBuffer().getNextPageToken();
                hasMore = mNextPageToken != null;
            }
        };

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (!connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    retrieveNextPage();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}
}
```

The ResultsAdapter.class:

```
public class ResultsAdapter extends DataBufferAdapter<Metadata> {

public ResultsAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    }
    Metadata metadata = getItem(position);
    TextView titleTextView =
            (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    titleTextView.setText(metadata.getTitle());
    return convertView;
}
}
```

I am including the dependency in the Gradle file like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.8.0'
```

The `Activity` in the `Manifest.xml` looks like the following:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.myproject.GoogleDriveActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=<google project number>"/>
</activity>
```

Please note that I have added the SHA1 to the Google API condole with the package name. Also, the fields in the content screen are filled out as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth).

When I try to run this code, I keep getting the following error message in the `onConnectionFailed` callback:

```
{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

Any idea on what could be going wrong? I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Just to clarify, where exactly you are getting the error? Sounds like your GoogleApiClient is not being connected, can you confirm that the onConnected method is being called?

Comment: @kroikie thanks for pointing that out. I edited my question. I am getting an error in `onConnectionFailed` callback. It is not being connected at all.

Comment: Could you confirm that the package name in your manifest file, is the same as the applicationId in your gradle file and the package name in the Client ID in dev console?

Comment: Hi @kroikie. I found the issue and added that as an answer to the question. Thanks for looking into this. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. The problem was the `debug key`. Essentially, I ran the `keytool` command and generated the `SHA1` which I then added to the API console on Google. I then ran the project from Android Studio. This was giving me the error.

I then created a new keystore from Android Studio -> Menu -> Build -> Generate signed apk. Ran the same command to generate `SHA1` which I uploaded to the API console. Then with the updated `apk` file, I was able to get the contents of the file.

The problem was that the key could not be authenticated by Google.

Comment: You've just run into a classic auth pitfall. The last-ditch /  double-check for this problem is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689832/google-drive-android-api-connectionresult-error/30448049#30448049).