# Sign in with google `gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: BadAuthentication` exception android

Tags: android, google-signin

I'm trying to add sign in with google button to my application. I followed the google documentation. But always the result is given for me is `null`. Therefore I cannot access `result.isSuccess()`. It gives `com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: BadAuthentication` exception. I followed all the steps correctly.

This is the sign in intent.

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1);
```

This is where I receive result

```
if (requestCode == 1) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
```

handleSignInResult() method

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.e("Result",result.getStatus().toString());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
        gtoken();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginListener.this,"Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**google sign in option**

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

I cannot find what is the reason. If you need to know anything please comment. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Read about the exception [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/UserRecoverableAuthException), use `getIntent()` and `startActivityForResult(Intent)`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thank you for your reply. My status code is `INTERNAL_ERROR`.

Comment: Then you need to add your app in the Google Dev console. With proper package names and key hashes. And enable singin API.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280794/error-connectionresultstatuscode-internal-error-resolution-null

Comment: share the code where u defined googleSigninOptions object and google api client object. that may be the source of exception.

Comment: @uncertain-eer I added the object to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you invoked so that you got UserRecoverableAuthException back.

But if you got result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == 8 (INTERNAL_ERROR), then you probably are missing a dev console registration.

[Occured an INTERNAL_ERROR when requestEmail from GoogleSignInOptions Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942692/occured-an-internal-error-when-requestemail-from-googlesigninoptions-android)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I downloaded android studio again and I changed my sha1 to the keystore file of my newly downloaded android studio's keystore file. It worked.