# Occured an INTERNAL_ERROR when requestEmail from GoogleSignInOptions Android

Tags: android, google-signin, google-identity

I'm following google instruction to add sign in with google button to my app. If I request sign in without `requestEmail()`

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .build();
```

It returns the result as successful. But if I request email, it occures an `INTERNAL_ERROR` as the status.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

returns

```
E/Result: Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

I'm stuck here. Any help highly appreciated. Please comment if you need further information about the code. Thank you

Comment: Same here, if i sign without the requestEmail() it works, but if i put the requestEmail() i will have the INTERNAL_ERROR and nothing works. I double checked the Credentials page and my keys... Nothing works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you get error code 8 (`INTERNAL_ERROR`), please double check your app registration in dev console. Note that every registered Android client is uniquely identified by the (package name, Android Signing Certificate SHA-1) pair. If you have multiple package names / signing certificate for your debug and production environments, make sure to register every pair of them. To verify:

1. Open the [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential) and select your project
2. Make sure every pair has an **Android** typed OAuth 2.0 client IDs. 
   To create a new OAuth 2.0 client ID for your Android client, select **New Credentials**->**OAuth2 Client ID** from the dropdown, select Android and input your Package name / Signing-certificate fingerprint there.

To get your signing key certificate SHA-1:

**Standard Debug Key**

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

**Other (Custom) Key**

`keytool -list -v -keystore $YOUR_KEYSTORE_LOCATION`

Comment: That was it. I was supposed to register both the keys, debug and production.