# Android Google Sign In fails with error code 8 (no message)

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-openid, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google Sign in to my application, but I get errors that I cannot understand.

I have configured everything according to the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/), but it would not authenticate me. I am presented with the login panel that shows my accounts, and the login activity OnActivityResult fires, when looking into the GoogleSignInResult, I have a [Status](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Status) with a statusCode 8 and no message.

It seems to be related to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#INTERNAL_ERROR), but it is a bit confusing.

Any idea ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35050443/5001016

Comment: Many thanks Steven, that did nail it indeed! For some reason I thought that 1)you could only have one Android credential line, 2)the debug certificate would be dealt with by Google "by magic"...
I got proven wrong, but you put me back on the right track.

Comment: Steven, if you want to re post your comment as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the answer to this question: [An `INTERNAL_ERROR` (8) occurred when requestEmail from GoogleSignInOptions on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35050443/5001016)

If you get error code 8 (`INTERNAL_ERROR`), please double check your app registration in dev console. Note that every registered Android client is uniquely identified by the (package name, Android Signing Certificate SHA-1) pair. If you have multiple package names / signing certificate for your debug and production environments, make sure to register every pair of them. To verify:

1. Open the [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential) and select your project
2. Make sure every pair has an **Android** typed OAuth 2.0 client IDs. 
   To create a new OAuth 2.0 client ID for your Android client, select **New Credentials**->**OAuth2 Client ID** from the dropdown, select Android and input your Package name / Signing-certificate fingerprint there.

To get your signing key certificate SHA-1:

**Standard Debug Key**

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

**Other (Custom) Key**

`keytool -list -v -keystore $YOUR_KEYSTORE_LOCATION`

Comment: Even after adding SHA-1 pair added to dev console. I am still seeing INTERNAL ERROR.

Attempt to save credential failed null 8
Resolving: Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}
STATUS: FAIL

Answer (score 0):

Good day. I ran into a similar problem and spent 1.5 days solving it.

Tips to help you:

1. First check valid the package name and fingerprint SHA1.
2. If your application did not pass verification and was not released, then make sure that the user to be authorized is in the list of testers (this can be checked in APIs & Service -> OAuth consent sreen -> Test users)

- There is a suspicion that all letters in the package name in android studio should be lowercase.

In my case, it helped to create a new project, transfer old files to it, and create a new OAuth Client IDs.