# Google Sign in gives INTERNAL_ERROR = 8 for new user

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, google-plus-signin

When I try to sign-in using G+ on an android app for an new user who is not been signed in on device google account, I get an `INTERNAL_ERROR with status 8` and mask stays for ever until user taps on masks. When we retry again for the same user i am getting the successful sign-in response.

Google sign-in options code :

```
    GoogleSignInOptions.Builder gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN);
            gso.requestEmail().requestProfile();
            String webClientId = clientOptions.optString(ARGUMENT_WEB_CLIENT_ID, null);
    gso.requestIdToken(webClientId);
    gso.requestServerAuthCode(webClientId, false);

GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(webView.getContext())
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso.build());

        this.mGoogleApiClient = builder.build();
```

**Note**: it works for user who have already signed into the device google account.

Comment: Hello.. thanks for reply.. i am not expecting any debugging help. I need to know if google supports new user sign-in for the applications using Google sigin-in. As i mentioned in my question posted above, i face this issue only when the user has not signed into device google account and tries to login to the app using google sign-in client library.

Comment: I suggest you add "I need to know..." part to the question. Telling us what kind of answer you're looking for is a big part of asking a good question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Google Sign In fails with error code 8 (no message)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229264/android-google-sign-in-fails-with-error-code-8-no-message)

Comment: I am encountering the same problem, its happening when a new email is added from the select email popup

Comment: This question is not a duplicate! I am facing same issue, problem is when on Select email dialog user taps on "Add new" option. I have no solution, it look's like google API bug.

Comment: Yes, this happens consistently for us @GordonFreeman … it's a known issue: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/358