# Google Play Services Sign-in INTERNAL ERROR

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-oauth

I have just started implementing Google Sign In API, this is my configuration:

I added this to gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
```

This is my OnCreate:

```
gso=new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this,this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
            .build();
```

This is how I invoke the sign-in process:

```
  Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGNIN_ID);
```

But it doesn't work and it says Google Play Services has stopped working, in the logs it says "INTERNAL ERROR"

I have linked my app to a service, I have the OAUTH2 code, I don't know what I'm doing wrong and am pretty much desperate, thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to check [Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting). Checking your package name and certificate fingerprint as suggested in this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942692/occured-an-internal-error-when-requestemail-from-googlesigninoptions-android) might also help.

Comment: I've actually managed to make it work, I think the .json configuration file was not working, thank you for your time anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add configuration file with  SHA-1 hash of your signing certificate.

[Configuration file to your project](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)

add google-services.json in app directory of your Android Studio project

Comment: I followed the link and it redirected me to Firebase, I got the json from there, and copied it to my app folder, still does not work.