# Google Sign In rarely gets INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android, google-signin

I've implemented Google Sign In in my app. It works fine on every device available to me.

But I've found in Crashlytics that some (very few) users get `INTERNAL_ERROR` code in `GoogleSignInResult`.

```
int code = result.getStatus().getStatusCode(); // 8==INTERNAL_ERROR
String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage(); // null
boolean isCancelled = result.getStatus().isCanceled(); // false
boolean isInterrupted = result.getStatus().isInterrupted(); // false
```

I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35050443/6182136) that usually `INTERNAL_ERROR` is caused by app's wrong configuration in Google Console, but in my case it isn't a reason because app works on most of devices.

So, how to find the reason of `INTERNAL_ERROR` while Google Sign In?

Comment: It's an internal error. That could mean Google's servers didn't respond, it could mean the user has an adblocker that breaks the sign-in flow, it could mean anything. Either mute the error in Crashlytics or restart the flow on that error code.