# Finding the source of ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm currently running into a problem where the code

```
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity, this,this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
```

works just fine, but

```
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity, this,this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .build();
```

doesn't want to connect, only returning

> ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}

There seems to be a **lot** of questions on this, but most of them only adress a specific scenario. So far it seems like my scenario would be unique, and therefore off-topic on this site. My product name is set in the developer console, the package matches and the signature is correct. The required apis are enabled, and no suggestion given in any topic seems to help out. It seems like only time, trial and error will solve this problem in my case.

Now the question arises however, how does one debug this problem? It seems to be such a common problem without a common resolution, so what steps would one take to find out how to resolve the problem?

Edit:

To get a bit more specific on this scenario, it seems like the problem lies somewhere with the `com.google.android.gms` service. That one crashes every time. Below this is the logcat of the following code:

```
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                Log.d("Snapshot", "3");
                googleApiClient.blockingConnect();
                Log.d("Snapshot", "4");
                return null;
            }

        }.execute();
```

The errors in this logcat are consistent and occur every time, Of course with varying timestamps and process ID's, and some of this is probably unrelated to the issue, but to me it's near impossible to filter this out.

```
07-03 16:05:52.025 23176-24251/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: 3

    --------- beginning of system
07-03 16:05:52.026 891-6829/? W/AppOps: Bad call: specified package com.google.android.gms under uid 10252 but it is really 10010
07-03 16:05:52.043 335-1227/? D/AudioPolicyManager: startOutput()--
07-03 16:05:52.043 335-1227/? I/AudioFlinger: vl# new track,stream:1,masterVolume:1.000000,typeVolume:0.501188,vlf:0.501160,vrf:0.501160
07-03 16:05:52.046 335-987/? D/audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: enter: stream(0xb59a3640)usecase(1: low-latency-playback) devices(0x2)
07-03 16:05:52.046 335-987/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
07-03 16:05:52.046 335-987/? D/hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
07-03 16:05:52.046 335-987/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 15, path =  0
07-03 16:05:52.051 335-987/? E/msm8974_platform: wdd add mixer_path low-latency-playback i2s prop_value 15055
07-03 16:05:52.052 335-987/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: done
07-03 16:05:52.175 891-1864/? D/ConnectivityService: listenForNetwork for NetworkRequest [ id=3904, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
07-03 16:05:52.175 891-1245/? D/ConnectivityService: handleRegisterNetworkRequest checking NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 382]
07-03 16:05:52.175 891-1245/? D/ConnectivityService: apparently satisfied.  currentScore=60
07-03 16:05:52.176 891-1245/? D/ConnectivityService: sending notification AVAILABLE for NetworkRequest [ id=3904, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
07-03 16:05:52.177 26026-26135/? D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524290
07-03 16:05:52.311 26026-26136/? W/DriveInitializer: Background init thread started
07-03 16:05:52.331 26141-26141/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews phoneId =0mMSimDataConnected =false
07-03 16:05:52.331 26141-26141/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews mMSimDataActivity =0
07-03 16:05:52.334 26141-26141/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming for phoneId: 0
07-03 16:05:52.335 335-985/? D/AudioPolicyManager: stopOutput() output 4, stream 1, session 785
07-03 16:05:52.335 335-985/? D/AudioPolicyManager: stopOutput()--
07-03 16:05:52.360 26026-26137/? I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
07-03 16:05:52.360 26026-26137/? I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
07-03 16:05:52.391 26026-26137/? D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
07-03 16:05:52.393 26026-26137/? D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
07-03 16:05:52.393 26026-26137/? I/asset: Success to oxygen resources /system/framework/oxygen-framework-res.apk
07-03 16:05:52.398 26026-26137/? D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
07-03 16:05:52.455 26026-26139/? I/GCore-Chimera-Crash: Cg0KB3ZJbmZyYTQQor84Gl8KHWNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC
                                                        5wbGF5LmdhbWVzEhQzLjcuMjMgKDI4Njc2MzctMDM4KRjWq-AR
                                                        IiMKHGNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC5nbXMuZ2FtZXMQsKvgEQ
                                                        ==
                                                        GCore-Chimera-Crash

                                                        --------- beginning of crash
07-03 16:05:52.458 26026-26139/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: highpool[0]
                                                   Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 26026
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'kau jwg.a' on a null object reference
                                                       at jzf.a(:com.google.android.gms:336)
                                                       at kip.a(:com.google.android.gms:11149)
                                                       at kip.b(:com.google.android.gms:415)
                                                       at kiq.run(:com.google.android.gms:1054)
                                                       at loq.run(:com.google.android.gms:53)
                                                       at itt.run(:com.google.android.gms:453)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                       at iyg.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-03 16:05:52.460 26026-26139/? E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                       at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                       at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler.<init>(AsyncQueryHandler.java:125)
                                                       at net.oneplus.odm.insight.tracker.AbstractTracker$TrackerAsyncQueryHandler.<init>(AbstractTracker.java:110)
                                                       at net.oneplus.odm.insight.tracker.AbstractTracker.<init>(AbstractTracker.java:60)
                                                       at net.oneplus.odm.insight.tracker.AppTracker.<init>(AppTracker.java:24)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:99)
                                                       at icd.uncaughtException(:com.google.android.gms:54)
                                                       at ibx.uncaughtException(:com.google.android.gms:62)
                                                       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-03 16:05:52.463 26026-26139/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26026 SIG: 9
07-03 16:05:52.489 891-3957/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.google.android.gms (pid 26026) has died
07-03 16:05:52.489 891-5403/? E/WifiService: Multicaster binderDied
07-03 16:05:52.489 891-1250/? D/ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ id=3904, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ], android.os.BinderProxy@d4be6da)
07-03 16:05:52.490 891-1245/? D/ConnectivityService: releasing NetworkRequest NetworkRequest [ id=3904, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
07-03 16:05:52.490 891-1245/? D/ConnectivityService: sending notification RELEASED for NetworkRequest [ id=3904, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
07-03 16:05:52.491 891-1245/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=3904, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
07-03 16:05:52.492 19485-19485/? V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]: service disconnected: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.AnalyticsService}
07-03 16:05:52.492 19485-19485/? V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]: Unexpected disconnect.
07-03 16:05:52.493 19485-19485/? V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]: service disconnected: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.AnalyticsService}
07-03 16:05:52.493 19485-19485/? V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]: Unexpected disconnect.
07-03 16:05:52.496 891-3957/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.service.GeoDataService in 1000ms
07-03 16:05:52.496 891-3957/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.drive.api.ApiService in 11000ms
07-03 16:05:52.496 891-3957/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService in 21000ms
07-03 16:05:52.497 891-3957/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.signin.service.SignInAsyncService in 31000ms
07-03 16:05:52.497 891-3957/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.measurement.service.MeasurementBrokerService in 31000ms
07-03 16:05:52.497 891-3957/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.signin.service.SignInBrokerService in 41000ms
07-03 16:05:52.497 891-3957/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService in 51000ms
07-03 16:05:52.508 23176-23176/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: Connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
07-03 16:05:52.513 23176-23176/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
07-03 16:05:52.529 891-5403/? V/WindowManager: not Base app: Adding window Window{3ad0e9e8 u0 nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor.SplashActivity} at 23 of 29
07-03 16:05:52.540 23176-24251/nl.dvandenberg.energymonitor D/Snapshot: 4
```

Edit 2:

I have managed to solve my own problem, by adding `.addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)` to the builder. I've got no idea as to why this works or is needed, but as long as it works I'll take it.

I'm not posting this as an answer, as in this question I'd like to focus on how to find the source of this issue, not on making a list of possible solutions.

Comment: Have you tried `mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)  
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();` yet? Moreover, try this demo project https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

Comment: @BNK Now I did, I think I've tried all possible combinations, but none of that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you read this link https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/issues/2 yet?

Comment: @BNK yup, ran through all of that. Haven't tried making a new project, but my app has already been published. Fortunately it works without this too, but backup and synchronisation is down because of it. Worst part, it worked before, but even the versions in which it used to work don't work any more.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? ticket discuss how to solve interal error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280794/error-connectionresultstatuscode-internal-error-resolution-null

Comment: @d.datul1990 yes, also without result.